# Android/Java: How to make a static write method

Tags: java, android, static

I currently have a write method to save a few variables and I would like to use this method throughout more than one class. I can but I need to use it in static places in those classes which won't work because the save method cannot be static.

Here's the method:

```
public void saveLesson(int lessons2, int problem2, int mlessons2, int mproblem2, String checkAccuracy) {
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    final String saved = new String(lessons + newline + problem + newline + mlessons + newline + mproblem + newline + dontCheckMaxString()); 
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;

    try {       
        fOut = openFileOutput("lessonStore.properties", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    try {
        osw.write(saved);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(Lessons.this, "Error while writing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        andEggs.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I guess my question is:
How do  I make that method useable throughout all my classes; static or nonstatic methods?

Comment: Make dontCheckMaxString() static too? What it does?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that in this code to the method's. Anyways there are methods involved with the saveLesson that cannot be static.

Comment: If your method needs an instance of the class, you won't be able to use it if you can't get an instance of the class.

Comment: I don't see where your method needs an instance of your class, it takes everything from params!

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I think when I make it static the line with the openFileOutput returns with it can't be a static void in order to put the openFileOutput in. It returns with: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method openFileOutput(String, int) from the type ContextWrapper"

Comment: Add a parameter of type Context to the method and then call openFileOutput on that Context object. In this way you can make the method static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Context via your method's parameters. Then you can call Context.openFileOutput.